# Hiding all UILabels in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have various UILabels that I would like to hide using a for-loop.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
 NSMutableArray * labelArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label1, *label2, *label3;
...
-(void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [labelArray initWithObjects:label1,label2,label3,nil];

 for(int i=0; i<sizeof(labelArray); i++){
  UILabel *label = [labelArray objectAtIndex:i];
  label.hidden = !label.hidden;
 }
}
```

When this is executed, the labels are not hidden. They have been "hooked up" in Interface Builder. What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: 1. did you alloc'd labelArray?
2. don't use sizeof(labelArray) but [labelArray count] to determine the index range. Don't forget that labelArray is a pointer and sizeof() will return the pointer size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not what `sizeof` is for. That's a compiler construct that tells you how many bytes a value takes up, which has no clue how many elements are in an NSMutableArray at runtime. You want:

```
for (UILabel *label in labelArray) {
    label.hidden = !label.hidden;
}
```

If that doesn't work, then your array does not contain the objects you believe it does — quite possibly, you've forgotten to actually create the array — simply sending `init` to nil does not create an object. Either way, you should probably be doing `labelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:label1,label2,label3,nil];`. `alloc` and `init` go together hand-in-glove.

Comment: That was it, I had forgotten to explicitly allocate. Thanks!